# Why is there a red underline error under the showsnackbar?

Tags: android, ios

void _showSnackBar(String text) {
scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
content: new Text(text),
));
}

void _showSnackBar(String text) {
scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
content: new Text(text),
));
}
//no red underline under showsnackbar

Comment: You need to provide some context details. What editor are you seeing the red underline in? What language are you writing in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.